# My picture Background Image doesn't appear

Tags: css, reactjs

I wanna my picture background appeared instead of "coucou" following my screenshot.
But this one doesn't want to appear on my website.

[image]

my html :

```
<Row className="background">
          <Col  className="blockConnexion" sm={12} md={7}>
            <h1 className="titreConnexion">Déjà membre?</h1>
            
              [...]
          </Col>
          <Col className="imageDeskServeur" md={5}>
       <h1>coucou</h1>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
```

my css :

```
.imageDeskServeur{
    display: block;
    background-image: url("/public/images/drink.jpg");
    width: 100%;

  }
```

Comment: try adding class to 'Container' instead of 'Row'.

Comment: try this `background-image: url("images/drink.jpg");`

Comment: try this:  `background-image: url(/public/images/drink.jpg);`   and And make sure the path you take is the right one